# Error in Eclipse -Could not find the main class(Running NFC Example)

Tags: java, eclipse, nfc

I am trying to run an example which I pulled out from [open-nfc.org](http://www.open-nfc.org). 
I have followed all the instructions provided by [this site](http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/sdk-edition/creating-a-java-example/), however when I am trying to run the program I am getting the following error 
`Error: Could not find or load main class Processing`

I have attached the program

```
package NFC;
import org.opennfc.*;

public class FinalNFC {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      NfcManager mgt = NfcManager.getInstance(null);

      System.out.println(mgt.getProperty("open_nfc.version"));

      try {
         System.out.println(mgt.getProperty("nfcc.firmware_version"));

      } finally {
         try {
            mgt.stop();
         } catch(NfcException e) {
            System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried searching for this problem in stack overflow but nothing is seemed to solve this issue !

I am new to the Eclipse, so step by step Solution is really appreciated.

**Else can anyone give me some site so that i can code in nfc using java ?**

Comment: How do you attempt to run your program, through eclipse or command line or what?

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the error.

Comment: I am getting the same output even if i print the Stack Trace ...

Comment: @user3414969 Stack Trace is being asked for because you have an error!

Comment: I may look fool , How to get the stack trace because i just added the line e.getStackTrace(); .... it would be helpful if u guide me !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Try running your program through native command line process, though your program syntactically seems ok but still that will give an idea about APIs as i could guess you're naive for eclipse.

Secondly, i had faced similar problem before what worked for me was re-configuring JVM.

Thirdly, What kind of project you have made in eclipse. For example if you are running Dynamic Web Project i.e. if you're running complete project itself then error you are getting is obvious. Then try running only the file by right clicking on it and select run file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it seems not to be helping me ...
1) I tried native command prompt to run the program but javac shows error to all NFC packages 
2) i have re configured the JVM doesnt seem to help this
3)I have tried to compile the file as independent Still i am getting the same output !!!

Comment: This is the VM Arguments that i have given in the 
-Xbootclasspath/p:open_nfc.jar -Dopennfc.config=1234 -Dsun.boot.library.path=. -Djava.library.path=C:\Projects\NFCTrial\Codings Examples\Core(Updated)\porting\jni\output\

Comment: Did you set the classpath for NFC APIs for compilation for command line execution. You need to download the APIs required for NFC.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly right click on your eclipse project and select "run as - Java Application". Then it will start searching main class and it will show you lots of classes then in search window type "FinalNFC" then select that class and run it.

Comment: It doesnt show any classes or so ... as soon as i give Run as -> Java Application I get the error "Error: Could not find or load main class Processing"